Cant use player.attach for playing the next video while creating the functionality for playing the next video
function Shaka({ videoData, getNextEpisodeId = () => {} }) {
const videRef = useRef(null);
const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);

async function init(videoData) {
    const player = new Shaka.player();
    await player.attach(videoRef.current); //Stops execution here in the second initialization for the next episode
    setPlayer(player);
    //await player.load(videoData.src)
}

useEffect(() => {
    //Player initialization code
    init(videoData);
}, []);

const handleNext = () => {
    if (player) {
        player.destroy();
    }

    getNextEpisodeId().then((data) => init(data));
};
return (
    <div>
        <video ref={videoRef} autoplay />
        <button onClick={handleNext}>Skip Next</button>
    </div>
);
}

I tried implementing next episode feature on shaka player,but failed.I have written the code for playing next episode.
The player.attach method does not work the second time I am loading it for the get next episode ,it reaches till there and it stops execution when I am trying to load the second time
